# Did Shosanna make her dress out of a Nazi banner?

Tags: character, inglourious-basterds

In the movie Inglourious Basterds, Shosanna Dreyfus appears as a stunning *woman in red* on the Nation's Pride premiere. This image contrasts dramatically with her previous appearances in casual (or even shabby) clothing. This remarkable shot features her just before she goes out to socialize with the Nazis attending the premiere. Considering the wartime, her dress seems to be out of place. One thing I noticed, though, is how similar the color of her dress is to the color of the Nazi banners Paris is drowned in. Could she make a dress out of one? If so, does it carry any special meaning?

[image: Shosanna in red]

Comment: This would be utterly speculative unless someone could find an interview about it with the costume designer/s...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one interview where they asked about the red dress, Anna Sheppard [explained](http://clothesonfilm.com/inglourious-basterds-costume-lowdown-by-anna-sheppard/5602/) why she chose the red dress intead of a black dress, which was the original idea:

> I thought that in the black dress, her character would disappear as she is so tiny. As it was the last day of her character’s life, **I didn’t want her to disappear in the crowds of people wearing beautiful evening gowns as her other costumes had a much more tomboy-ish feel to them. I wanted her to look beautiful and very feminine, hence the red dress with a very seductive shape.**

The special you mentioned in the question would be look pretty sexy (damn, she was!) in the character's last day of life.